# MVC - How to Return Multiple Attributes while using a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So basically you can refer to [this](https://www.excel-university.com/select-drop-down-item-vlookup-return-multiple-attributes/) in order to have a clearly view on what I want to achieve in my website. 
The corresponding input such as `Price` and `Item` will get the information of the selected Gift Basket from database and appended inside the input tag so that the user can adjust the price or adding some item the the customer wanted.

**Before Selecting a Gift Basket.**
[image]

**After Selecting a Gift Basket.**
[image]

Is there any reference or example I can refer to in order to achieve this funtion

Answer (score 0):

1- in the dropdown list add htmlAttributes onchange

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GiftBasket, null, "--Select Gift Basket--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control ", onchange = "getprice()" }
```

2- insert below script  to get price and item from controller

```
<script>
    //get price & Item
    function getprice() {
    var strSelected1 = "";
    $("#GiftBasket option:selected").each(function () {
        strSelected1 += $(this)[0].value;
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/your-Controller/getGiftBasket?GiftBasketID=" + strSelected1,
        type: "post",
        cache: false,



        success: function (result) {

            
            document.getElementById('price').value = result[0].price;
            document.getElementById('item').value = result[0].item;
           

        },

        error: function () {
            alert("something wrong");
        }
    });
};
</script>
```

3- insert below JsonResult to the controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult getGiftBasket(int? GiftBasketID)
        {
            

            var GiftBasketitem = db.Giftitem.Where(e => e.GiftBasketID== GiftBasketID).Select(e => new { e.item,e.price });
            return Json(GiftBasket, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: May I ask why you written like this `$("#GiftBasket option:selected").each(function () {
        strSelected1 += $(this)[0].value;
    });`

Comment: @FENR1RAce to get the selected option value and send it to the controller by ajax URL